# Way to reveal big twist in fantasy world

Tags: plot, fantasy

In my fantasy story, a new group of people come to this empire seemingly peacefully. But soon, they begin to blame  these magical people for an assassination of the empire's empress, giving the crown to whoever captures and delivers the most people into the palace.

This sends the protagonist, who is a magic user, into hiding, and soon develops a team of other magical refugees. However, one day a person comes to them who is from these newcomers.

It turns out that she achieved the magical abilities randomly and was nearly captured by her own people, but escaped. But in truth, these people have to find a weapon hidden beneath the ground in order to kill a god that has destroyed their empire, and they are using the magical people as fuel. The visitor-magic wielder does not know any of this and only knows that there has been a disaster in her home and that they have come here for safety. Somehow they need to figure it out on the way.

What I don't know is **how to reveal this big twist**.

I know this is broad so leave questions below. 
And sorry in advance if this is really bad as this is my first question here.

Comment: Can you please edit your question a little bit? It's a little difficult to read as it is now.

Comment: Hello @Unhappymarshmellow and welcome to Writers SE! Your question is not working really well for the guidelines of this community (which you can read here: https://writers.stackexchange.com/help). You are not asking a specific question, but rather asking "how to write" a passage. Try to edit your question being more specific, so that answers can be less open as possible. What is it you want to know? How to introduce plot points or plot twists?  How to reveal information? Try search in the community, maybe somebody already answered something similar.

Comment: What do you mean with "how to reveal the big twist"? You just revealed it to us. What's making it harder to do in your story?

Comment: @B Altmann I need to figure out a way to impriment it in a logical but entertaining way.

Comment: Asking "what should I write" is generally frowned upon here, but here's my idea: Have your characters go after the missing magic wielders. If those people are being used to fuel a machine, they should be close to it. Your characters can find the machine while looking for them.

Answer (score 3):

Is your big twist a final twist, or it is a mid-story twist?

There are two general ways to present a twist: at climax or post-climax.

First, the story goes with pre-twist expectations and enters into its climax (or false climax), when protagonist is fully expected to triumph or perish. Then, in one moment, everything is upended - instead of dying, protagonist triumphs, or his/her victory becomes hollow ("[Luke, I am your father!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bv20ZoBcdO8)", "[Round up the usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXuBnz6vtuI)").

For post-climax, story goes through the climax and audience believes that this is, essentially, the end of story. And then, when nobody expects any more action, the hammer falls ("[They don't know they are dead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oU1Hg__9_aM)", "[Convince  me!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYXXhn9fMYs)").

For mid-story twists, you have more flexibility and generally need only to care that the twist is both unexpected and momentous ([warning: violence](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rgDvP39Lqw)).

Answer (score 2):

#### With a bang

If you want a big plot twist to have a lasting effect so that your readers will remember it for a long time, you should try to seed a few small hints here and there that something will happen in the buildup, but you should try to keep it a secret until your protagonist finds out what it is.

The moment they do find out about this they should find out everything and it should feel for reader as if the whole world came crashing down on your protagonist.

This is a big thing and it should be treated as such. It will change how the character who finds this out views his world and it should change how your reader views your book.

Keep it all secret and then let it all out at once. Make it a grand event. Dedicate enough space to it. And be sure to show the conflict that arises from this revelation for your characters.